# How we can check Google cloud tcp load balancer live logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to  check google cloud tcp load balancer logs from either G cloud or on Console.

Comment: As far as I know there is a feature request opened with this matter [link](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/70662343)

Comment: the link is not working ...can you pls help me out.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is a feature request opened with this matter [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70662343)